# IShellLink::SetIconLocation translates my icon path into %Program Files% which is WRONG

Tags: c++, windows-shell

Does anyone know how to correct for this behavior?

Currently, when our installer installs our application, it obtains an **IShellLink**, then loads it up with the data necessary for our shortcut icon (in the start menu & desktop), and then uses **IPersistFile::Save** to write out the shortcut.

The problem is that the path specified for the icon, via **IShellLink::SetIconLocation**, is transformed into using **%ProgramFiles%...** which... for x64, is WRONG.

I've noticed that lots of other 32 bit software has this failing under x64 - but then I assumed that they were using **%ProgamFiles%** themselves, as a literal element in their .lnk creation code.  However, it appears to be that **IShellLink** is forcing this bug into existence, and I don't have a work-around (or perhaps that the link property editor in the shell is responsible for the problem and the underlying link is okay).

A few Google searches have turned up nothing... has anyone else encountered this or know of an article / example of how to force x64 windows to not muck this up?

Clarifying example:

```
hr = m_shell_link->SetIconLocation("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Acme\\Prog.exe", 0);
```

Will result in a shortcut which has the correct icon, but when you press "Change icon" in the shortcut properties page, will report *"Windows can't find the file %ProgramFiles%\Acme\Prog.exe."*)

Comment: I observed the same problem on 64 bit Windows 10 with 32 bit app in Program Files (x86). But after making several tests (convert LNK file into TXT file, delete, create, delete, create the same link with TotalCommander, and other things) the icon is suddenly correct. This behavior is inconsistent! I start the same application (unchanged) which creates the link in the same folder and now it works ALWAYS correctly. Very weird. Has this to do with the icon cache not being updated??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the name into a short filename, and it will only convert the drive letter, yet keep the correct path.

```
        PWCHAR pIcon = L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Myfoo\\Bar.exe";
        DWORD dwLen = GetShortPathName(pIcon, NULL, 0);
        PWCHAR pShort = NULL; 
        if (dwLen) {
            pShort = new WCHAR[dwLen];
            dwLen = GetShortPathName(pIcon, pShort, dwLen);
            if (!dwLen) {
                delete [] pShort;
                pShort = NULL;
            }
        }

        if (NULL == pShort) {
            psl->SetIconLocation(pIcon,iTmp);
        } else {
            psl->SetIconLocation(pShort,iTmp);
        }
        delete [] pShort;
```

Comment: Acceptable.  I'd really rather have someone from MS fix their bug.  Or better yet, go back in time and slap the douche who decided that 32bit software should have its Program Files renamed, instead of forcing new x64 to use a new path.

Answer (score 3):

As user "pointoforder" points out in this [issue report on GitHub](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/issues/21#issuecomment-10274745), another fix is to unset the `SLDF_HAS_EXP_ICON_SZ` flag and remove the `EXP_SZ_ICON_SIG` data block from the `IShellLinkDataList` object. [This comment](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/issues/21#issuecomment-10319791) has the according Delphi code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

When I was looking for a solution to create shortcuts in C# I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4897733/2843772) on StackOverflow.

Now I came across the problem described in this thread. I'm unsure where to post my solution but I guess this is the right place.

I added IShellLinkDataList and changed the Save() method as below:

```
#region IShellLinkDataList Interface
[ComImportAttribute()]
[GuidAttribute("45e2b4ae-b1c3-11d0-b92f-00a0c90312e1")]
[InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
private interface IShellLinkDataList
{
    void AddDataBlock(IntPtr pDataBlock);
    void CopyDataBlock(uint dwSig, out IntPtr ppDataBlock);
    void RemoveDataBlock(uint dwSig);
    void GetFlags(out uint pdwFlags);
    void SetFlags(uint dwFlags);
}
#endregion

private const uint SLDF_HAS_EXP_ICON_SZ = 0x00004000;
private const uint EXP_SZ_ICON_SIG = 0xA0000007;

public void Save(string linkFile)
{   
    // Save the object to disk
    uint flags;
    if (linkA == null)
    {
        ((IShellLinkDataList)linkW).GetFlags(out flags);
        flags = flags & ~SLDF_HAS_EXP_ICON_SZ;
        ((IShellLinkDataList)linkW).SetFlags(flags);
        ((IShellLinkDataList)linkW).RemoveDataBlock(EXP_SZ_ICON_SIG);
        ((IPersistFile)linkW).Save(linkFile, true);
        shortcutFile = linkFile;
    }
    else
    {
        ((IShellLinkDataList)linkA).GetFlags(out flags);
        flags = flags & ~SLDF_HAS_EXP_ICON_SZ;
        ((IShellLinkDataList)linkA).SetFlags(flags);
        ((IShellLinkDataList)linkA).RemoveDataBlock(EXP_SZ_ICON_SIG);
        ((IPersistFile)linkA).Save(linkFile, true);
        shortcutFile = linkFile;
    }
}
```

Comment: 9 years later and Windows 10 still has the same bug, but luckily the solution with SLDF_HAS_EXP_ICON_SZ and EXP_SZ_ICON_SIG also works. Thank you!