# C# ShortCut Path Modification

Tags: c#, parameters, shortcut

I've created a program which generates a shortcut to a specific EXE selected via the open file dialog, using some library. I got it to work but I want the program to add a parameter to the Target path to make it look like this: (`"E:\Cod4\iw3mp.exe" +Seta Map mp_crash`). What can I do to add the (`+ Seta Map mp_Crash`) part after the `"` mark without removing it or ruining the extension of the .exe?

Here is block of the code I wrote to add the parameter:

```
label1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

shortcut.TargetPath = label1.Text + " Seta Map mp_crash";

shortcut.Save();
```

This code will add the seta part to the target but it will ruin the extension and it will look like this `"E:\Cod4\iw3mp.exe Seta Map mp_crash "`

Please help.
here is the full code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using IWshRuntimeLibrary;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication18

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form

    {


        public Form1()

        {

            InitializeComponent( 
            );

        }
        public void CreateShortcut()
        {

            object shDesktop = (object)"Desktop";
            WshShell shell = new WshShell();
            string shortcutAddress = (string)shell.SpecialFolders.Item(ref shDesktop) + @"\Server.lnk";
            IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);
            shortcut.Description = "Server Shortcut";
            shortcut.Hotkey = "Ctrl+Shift+N";
            var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.ShowDialog();
            shortcut.TargetPath = '"' + ofd.FileName + '"' + "+Seta Map mp_crash";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            CreateShortcut();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //  var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
         //   ofd.ShowDialog();
        //    string shortcut = '"' + ofd.FileName + '"' + "+Seta Map mp_crash";
         //   openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "EXE";
      //  / //  openFileDialog1.FileName = "Iw3mp.exe";
         //  DialogResult result2 = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
       //   label1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
       //   a = label1.Text;

        //    if (result2 == DialogResult.OK) 
        //   {
        //    }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your updated question, try this

```
shortcut.TargetPath = ofd.FileName;
shortcut.Arguments = "Seta Map mp_crash";
```

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication18.exe

Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.

Comment: What line throws that error? The code above just returns a string with quote marks around the value of `label1.Text` and the command line switch. You could add a `-` just before the `{1}` to delimit the argument.

Comment: the shortcut.targetpath line

Comment: You're welcome :) Please select the check mark on the left to mark this thread as answered.

Comment: thanx i did't knew how to select best answer till now :D

Comment: No problem! It's slightly different from a lot of other forums but I think it works well :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
        var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.ShowDialog();
        string shortcut = '"' + ofd.FileName + '"' + " +Seta Map mp_crash";
```

that should format the string how you want it...

Comment: same error An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication18.exe

Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range

Answer (score 1):

thanx every one for spending time to discover what i couldn't especially KeyboardP and his working code , thanx

```
shortcut.TargetPath = ofd.FileName;
shortcut.Arguments = "Seta Map mp_crash";
```