# Add an item to Windows Explorer context menu through an installer

Tags: c#, wpf, registry, windows-explorer-integration

For educational purposes, I'm developing a simple App in WPF using C#.

The App will be distributed without using the Install Shield Wizard, especially when it is launched for the first time it must be able to configure the system registers for an App entry to appear in the Windows Explorer drop down menu.

I roughly understand that I have to change the system registers (regedit.exe) but I have not clear three things:

1. which registers should I change and how?
2. how the App can cheks that this entry in the system logs is already there? And eventually add it programmatically if it is missing?
3. how do I associate a functionality (class or function) between the App and a click on the drop-down menu item? (I have a rough idea that you should use command line arguments, but how do that?)

Comment: That wasn't difficult to google... https://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024785/how-to-create-start-menu-shortcut this will help you.