# How to pin an app to the start menu Win 11

Tags: c#, .net-4.8, windows-11, startmenu, pinned-shortcut

I would like to pin an app to the Win 11 Start Menu in a C# program. Having searched on StackOverflow I found this ([How to create start menu shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024785/how-to-create-start-menu-shortcut)) which worked in that it created a shortcut in the Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartMenu directory but when I press the WinKey my app doesn't appear.

So, my question is:

How do you persuade Win 11 to show all of the shortcuts in the Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartMenu directory.

I did try restarting Windows Explorer but that didn't help.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/primary-tile-apis#pin-your-primary-tile