# how to add icon to application's shortcut in desktop

Tags: c#, winforms, icons, shortcut

I want when user runs my c# application , the application will create a desktop shortcut to run application. I use this code :

```
private void appShortcutToDesktop(string linkName)
{
    string deskDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(deskDir + "\\" + linkName + ".url"))
    {
        string app = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        writer.WriteLine("[InternetShortcut]");
        writer.WriteLine("URL=file:///" + app);
        writer.WriteLine("IconIndex=0");
        string icon = app.Replace('\\', '/');
        writer.WriteLine("IconFile=" + icon);
        writer.Flush();
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    appShortcutToDesktop("MyName");
}
```

This code creates shortcut but I want to put `myicon.ico` for shortcuts icon .
how can I do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create shortcut on desktop C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897655/create-shortcut-on-desktop-c-sharp)

Comment: I saw this ,this did now help me !

Comment: Replace `writer.WriteLine("IconFile=" + icon);` with `writer.WriteLine("IconFile=" + pathToMyIconDotIco);`

Comment: @DavidArno error :  The name 'pathToMyIconDotIco' does not exist in the current context c:\users\soheil\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\shortcut\shortcut\Form1.cs

Comment: Well of course it doesn't. You have to create it! :) Apologies if that wasn't clear. It's the path of your `myicon.ico` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following steps:

> 1. Right click on your project in the ***Solution Explorer*** and select ***Properties***.
> 2. ***Application tab***
> 3. ***Icon and manifest***
> 4. Select ***icon***