# WinForms app icon not displaying in taskbar

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem when I add an Icon in my Windows Forms application. The icon is
not displaying in the Taskbar:

[image]

I'm trying this:

```
this.Icon = new Icon(Application.StartupPath + "//" + "logo-pages.ico");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add icon to application shortcut in desktop c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472297/how-to-add-icon-to-application-shortcut-in-desktop-c-sharp)

Comment: this.Icon = new Icon(Application.StartupPath + "//" + "logo-pages.ico");   working in load

Comment: @mahmoud Have you tried to add icon to your form in designer?

Comment: @user2946329 Taskbar icon is the icon you set for form. That answer icon is application icon that will be used for application file or shortcut to application. –

Comment: i had this before but it was only if i run the app in vs debugger try running the app from it's directory or maybe in Release mode

Comment: thanks all fine working have to solution add in designer form or coding in page load