# How to create Icons for a Desktop Application in Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I have an application which has been used in Win7.  I am now moving to Win10. It is a standard application and not a universal one.

My application icon look ugly in the Windows 10 app menu and in the start menu (mainly because it is not a flat icon with transparent background).  Can someone point me to a guide on what kind of icons .ico/.png files I am suppose to make for my application in a Windows 10 environment.

I imagine I could make a flat white icon with a transparent background but what happens when themes change or the file is viewed in a white background?

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472297/how-to-add-icon-to-applications-shortcut-in-desktop

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But no that is not what I am looking for.  I am looking more at the design color and size of icons for Windows 10.