# C# Create shortcut

Tags: c#

I am trying to make an app that creates a shortcut for selected program. When the program starts, it shows all programs in `listbox` and you can search for the program. How to create a shortcut from selected program inside `listbox` and name it like selected program. I used this code but I only created a shortcut for notepad.
[Create shortcut on desktop C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897655/create-shortcut-on-desktop-c-sharp)

```
private void CreateShortcut()
{
    object shDesktop = (object)"Desktop";
    WshShell shell = new WshShell();
    //string shortcutAddress = (string)shell.SpecialFolders.Item(ref shDesktop) + @"\Notepad.lnk";
    string shortcutAddress = (string)shell.SpecialFolders.Item(ref shDesktop) + @"\Notepad.lnk";
    IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress );
    shortcut.Description = "New shortcut for a Notepad";
    shortcut.Hotkey = "Ctrl+Shift+N";
    shortcut.TargetPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolde r.System) + @"\notepad.exe";
    shortcut.Save();
}
```

Comment: you should show the code that doesn't works

Comment: Also, you are probably going to need to pass some arguments to that function, else how will it know what program it's meant to be adding?

Comment: Here is my program source code: http://pastebin.com/Fy0CM0EU

Comment: you're using a private session. Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry for that,I changed it now to public!!!

Comment: This question is really about using a form control selection as a parameter for creating a shortcut rather than how to create the shortcut itself, which is already implemented.  The linked code should be edited into the question as well as a description of how it's lacking or not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CSharpLib](https://github.com/Ferrell-Technology/CSharpLib/wiki). Download it [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CSharpLib/2.4.5) or, if you're using Visual Studio, enter `Install-Package CSharpLib -Version 4.0.0` in Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console. It has a couple methods in the `Shortcut` class that you can use for shortcut manipulation. For example:

```
using CSharpLib;

Shortcut shortcut = new Shortcut();
shortcut.CreateShortcutToFile("target_file", "shortcut_file");
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `shortcut.TargetPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolde r.System) + @"\notepad.exe";` to `shortcut.TargetPath = YourListBox.getSelected();`

EDIT: if `getSelected()` doesn't work, try `getSelectedItem()`