# Is there an alternative for creating shortcuts with IWshRuntimeLibrary in ASP.Net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-shell

I have an ASP.Net core 2.0 API which has access to a folder structure. Within this structure the API should be able to create folder shortcuts (.lnk).

In a .net environment I'd use the IWshRuntimeLibrary to create those shortcuts. But of course with the ASP.Net core advantage of being cross-plattform those OS specific things like COM objects won't work.

So the question is: what would be an alternative to do this in asp.net core 2.0?

Comment: Have you tried my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14632782/403671