# Find program using Cortana/Search bar in C#

Tags: c#, windows, cortana

I want that my program is accessible when typing the name in the Cortana bar/Search bar.

Do I have to change something in the registry or do I have to move my program to a specific folder? I have no idea.

Kind regards

Comment: You should be able to find your compiled program by typing it's full name with the .exe extension.

Comment: I dont want to type .exe behind.

Comment: Here is an example image: http://prntscr.com/l67fah

Comment: If you don't want to type the .exe you can add an installer project to your program and install your program. Assuming you are using Visual Studio you can install the project [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects). Note that this is the installer project for Visual Studio 2017. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0v6hmumCFU&t=67s) is a video on how to set up this installer. After you have build it, you can simple right click on it and install your program.

Comment: This installer will create a .msi file which can also give to other people to install your program properly.

Comment: I already have an installer. The installer changes something in the registry so that you can see the application in the program list of windows. But what exactly does the installer changes in the registry?

Comment: Add a shortcut to your desktop or to this folder **C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs**. The assemblies used in your app are added to the registry as far as i know. But this is a whole other question. This should answer your original question

Comment: Thanks, please post as an answer so I can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a shortcut to your desktop or to this folder: C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

Comment: How to create a shortcut: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897655/create-a-shortcut-on-desktop