# IWshRuntimeLibrary is not recognized in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, winforms, shell

Hi I am writing a C# WinForms program that needs to create a shortcut from the **shell:appsfolder** folder. I am trying to use the **IWshRuntimeLibrary**, but Visual Studio 2022 marks it as an error, although I have added the reference **Windows Script Host Object Model** to the project.

I have even tried to manually add the DLL **interop.iwshruntimelibrary.dll** to the project as an asset, but no good.

Please help.

Comment: You probably want to use [IShellLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishelllinkw) instead of that decrepit scripting lib

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it and give feedback.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14632782/7444103